# How do I ensure that writes to USB disk on network are flushed?

Tags: networking, samba, usb-drive, synchronization

I have recently added an Orange Livebox ADSL router to my LAN (as an additional WiFi Access Point) and also as a network disk server.

This is an Arcadyan router rebadged by Orange for the Spanish market. It supports FAT32 only.

I can write to and read from data sticks plugged into the router's USB port from my Linux laptop using

```
smb://192.168.x.y
```

I am thinking of buying a USB disk to act as a network server so that I can backup my files from Linux and maybe also from MacOS etc.

I am familiar with unmounting USB data sticks attached to my laptop in order to flush all written data to the device.

*Is there something I can use to make sure that my router also would flush all the data to its disk?*

The router gets rebooted from time to time and there are occasional power cuts.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could add a cron job to run `sync` regularly, e.g. every minute or even every 10 seconds.
2. You could add these variables to your rc.local or sysctl:

```
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 1048576
vm.dirty_bytes = 4194304
```

This will *not* completely solve the issue but will make it less critical if a power loss occurs. Probably you could make both variables zero but it may affect IO performance a lot.

3. You could patch the sources of whichever network daemon you're using (e.g. smbd/vsftpd/etc) to call fflush() after closing a file.

Unfortunately I am not aware of any ready solutions.

Comment: "You could add a cron job to run sync regularly" So sync on my laptop would flush the data from the router to its disk? In that case I could write a script to do my backups to include calls to sync.

Comment: It's a cron job **for the router**. Syncing on your laptop will do nothing.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose I could try and find out what operating system my router uses, if any, and see if I can run software on it.